# Collecting sub-expressions of a multivariate polynomial function in Sympy

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I have a degree 6 multivariate equation in `x` and `y` written in Sympy, e.g.

```
eqn = a*x**6 + b*x**5*y + c*x**4*y + d*x**3*y + e*x**3*y**2 + ...
```

Is there a way to collect `(x**2+y**2)` and rearrange them into the following format?

```
eqn2 = A*(x**2+y**2)**3 + B*(x**2+y**2)**2 + C*(x**2+y**2) + D
```

`A, B, C, D` can be in `x, y`.

So far I have only tried `collect(eqn, x**2 + y**2)` and it returned the original equation.

Thank you!

Comment: Speaking mathematically, what's the difference between (`A*(x**2+y**2)*3 + B*(x**2+y**2)*2` and `(3*A+2*B)*(x**2+y**2)`?

Comment: Oops, my bad. That's supposed to be `**3` and `**2`. I'll correct it. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I am not very sure if I used the correct terms as well (sub-expressions?), so I will welcome suggestions to better write the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a temporary symbol `z = x**2 + y**2` and replace `x**2` with `z - y**2`, then expand and restore:

```
>>> ex
A*x**6 + 3*A*x**4*y**2 + 3*A*x**2*y**4 + A*y**6 + B*x**4 + 2*B*x**2*y**2 +
B*y**4 + C*x**2 + C*y**2 + D
>>> ex.subs(x**2, z - y**2).expand().subs(z, x**2 + y**2)
A*(x**2 + y**2)**3 + B*(x**2 + y**2)**2 + C*(x**2 + y**2) + D
```

Although that works, perhaps a more direct thing to do is separate the expression by coefficients A-D and then factor those collections of terms:

```
def separatevars_additively(expr, symbols=[]):
    free = set(symbols) or expr.free_symbols
    d = {}
    while free:
        f = free.pop()
        expr, dep = expr.as_independent(f, as_Add=True)
        if dep.has(*free):
            return None
        d[f] = dep
    if expr:
        d[0] = expr
    return d

>>> coeff = var("A:D")
>>> separatevars_additively(ex, coeff)
{B: B*x**4 + 2*B*x**2*y**2 + B*y**4, A: A*x**6 + 3*A*x**4*y**2 + 3*A*x**2*y**4 + A*y**6, D: D, C: C*x**2 + C*y**2}
>>> Add(*[factor(i) for i in _.values()])
A*(x**2 + y**2)**3 + B*(x**2 + y**2)**2 + C*(x**2 + y**2) + D
```

Comment: I added another method that is perhaps a bit more robust.